# Use javsascript escape keypress to untoggle window shut

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the first bit of js toggling a div that helps users see current conversions.  I was hoping to tie in the escape keypress to close the popup.  I know the keypress code (which you can see below my fn) but my syntax isn't coming through tying them together.   Any help is oh so very welcome!

```
/* currency converter */
$('#link-currency').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#popup-currency').toggleClass('active');
});

$('body').keypress(function (e) {
    alert(e.which);
    if(e.which == 27){
        // Close my modal window
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't you just need to add `$('#popup-currency').removeClass('active')` inside the `if` statement in your `keypress` handler?

Answer (score 0):

Try `keyup` on the document:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
     $('#popup-currency').removeClass('active')
   }
});
```